# CAS and Spring Security special characters

Tags: encoding, spring-security, cas

I have 2 applications which uses CAS. I have problem, because when I ask CAS about user assigned to ticket I've become wrong encoded answer. There's any special characters(from UTF-8). 
I set properly char encoding in web.xml and changed settngs in server to allow UTF-8, but it still doesn't work. Have you any idea what can be a problem?
In Cas20ServiceTicketValidator in cas response I become:
`albaner.dÄ…b`

but I expect:
`albaner.döb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please post your web.xml file.

I would recommend you to include the following in your web.xml on the cas client,

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

My recommendation is based on the following content in the following link,
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.9.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#cas-singlelogout

Though this documentation reference is strictly for on single logout, however, i felt that your encoding issue is similar.

> When using the SingleSignOutFilter you might encounter some encoding issues. Therefore it is recommended to add the CharacterEncodingFilter to ensure that the character encoding is correct when using the SingleSignOutFilter. Again, refer to JASIG’s documentation for details. The SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener ensures that when an HttpSession expires, the mapping used for single logout is removed.